# IPN how to add the users username to the Paypal transaction (PHP)

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

So I've added this untested code to my IPN

```
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment and mark item as paid.

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

    include 'connect.php';
    if($payment_status == "completed")
    {
        mysql_query('UPDATE `users` SET `is_member`= 1 WHERE `username` == $username')
    }
    else
    {
       mysql_query('UPDATE `users` SET `is_member`= 0 WHERE `username` == $username')
    }
```

essentially altering the data dependent on the payment_status. The problem I have though is that paypal have no idea what username is. How would I give paypal this information? do I do it through the subscribe button or change the html code?

Comment: hi again, before redirecting customer to paypal are you saving the customer detail in database along with the subscription detail?

Comment: yeah I already have the username, email and password stored

Comment: and you also saving the subscription or order detail into database and passing the value to paypal which you are getting back here `$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];` right?

Comment: I'm not Googling to check right now, but if I remember correctly, you can pass any data you want to the PayPal API and it will pass it back..

Comment: the is_member is always set to 0, any item that they purchase will set the is_member to 1, whether it be 1, 3 or 6 month subscription.

Comment: @Adelphia yes but if OP is saving the data into database before redirecting the user to paypal and if the user detail is also saved into database then why need to pass more data to paypal and receive from paypal, makes things more complicated.

Comment: but is it possible for paypal and my database to know which user is making the transaction if I'm not sending paypal any information about the user?

Comment: @SmallLegend i m assuming you have a table where you are saving member subscription detail and it should have the user id too coz thats how you can find out which user bought what subscription, so all you need to fetch that user id back from member subscription table against this `$item_number` and then update the user table.

Comment: I have a users table, containing id, username,email,password, ismember. It shouldn't matter what subscription they buy because its a recurring service any subscription they buy will make is_member = 1. Maybe I'm looking at this from the wrong perspective

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly? You need to process a payment and then update a database with the payment info, but you can't figure out which user to credit the payment to? - If that's correct then all you need to do is pass the user ID or username to the Paypal API then Paypal will pass it back so you can use it to update the database.

Comment: Yes that exactly correct, the question is, how do I pass the user ID or username

Comment: i think you should have 3 tables, one for subscription, one for user, one for payment detail which you will get from paypal, off-course you have to save the transaction id too, the subscription  id should be the order id, coz while order id must be unique for every payment to paypal and subscription table must has user id from user-table against the user who buy subscription and payment table has subscription order id so you know against what transaction what subscription has been paid

Comment: this  `$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];` transaction id from paypal, where you are planning to save it, you must save it against every successful payment

Comment: Okay, so I'll create tables like you said. All the information from the transaction should be sent to my database through my ipn listener?

Comment: And what specific information should it be necessary for me to keep?

Comment: **users**: id,username,email,password,
**boldsubscription**:pd_id, is_member user_id
**payment details**: u_id

Comment: in payment table, save details you are getting in IPN from paypal, txn-id, payment status, date amount etc, and also you can fetch the user from user table against the `$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];`

Comment: but I won't be able to fetch that user, because not everyone that has signed up for the website will have used the same email as their paypal account

Comment: in IPN if you echo this `$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];` what you get and does it equal to `pd_id` of subscription table

Comment: i will be away for an hour so, subscription table `sub_id, user_id, payment_id`  and any other detail you like to save now user table `user_id, name, member_status, etc etc` now payment table `payment_id, sub_id, transaction_id, payment_status, datetime, etc etc` now when you send customer to paypal, make sure the order id or item number must be `sub_id` so in IPN you will receive it back `$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];` now all you need is fetch the subscription detail from subscription table and you can also fetch `user_id` from subscription table and then update user table.

Comment: Brilliant, so I've adjusted my database accordingly, now what modifications must I make to my IPN listener?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options here to complete your user/membership reconciliation with IPN,

1. Store "username" / "email" into your database during the checkout, and when payment is completed, read the `$payer_email` from IPN POST-back and make the data matching with your database entries (order details)

*Though this requires the least change on your code, it would fail to work when user uses a different email account (PayPal account) to pay*

2. **(Recommended)** Use the "invoice" parameter to uniquely identify an order for reconciliation.
   Generate an unique invoice ID and store it along with username / email to your database at the checkout; Pass that "invoice" tag to PayPal, and IPN will return the same when the payment is completed; grab the `$invoice` value and map it with your order data entry.

Some references here for further details:

[IPN Variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/)

Check here for how to add the "invoice" field:

For Standard Payment buttons, see [HTML Variables for PayPal Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/)

For Express Checkout APIs, see [SetExpressCheckout API Operation (NVP)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)

Comment: How would I make the modifications in my IPN to address the recommended step?

Comment: add a line to read the "invoice" variable, $order_invoice = $_POST['invoice']; and select userID from your database order table where invoice = $order_invoice, to match the userID with the transacction